# How to implement a stored procedure for my case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I will implement a SSRS summary data report with following data records from one table.

```
ID         Part                 Type                Value
------------------------------------------------------------
1          Payroll              State Tax           2010
1          Payroll              City Tax             500
1          Payroll              Medical              300
2          Payroll              State Tax           2000
2          Payroll              City Tax             400
3          Payroll              FICA                 200
1          Refund               State Tax           -500
1          Refund               Medical             -100
3          Payroll              FICA                 200
1          Refund               State Tax           -500
1          Refund               Medical             -100
```

How do I implement a stored procedure to produce following result by summing same `Type` values for each Part so it is easy to build the SSRS report? Thanks a lot!

```
Type                      Payroll                  Refund                 Total
State Tax                 4010                      -500                  3600
City Tax                  900                        0                    900
FICA                      400                        0                    400
Medical                   300                       -100                  200
```

Comment: Show what have you tried.. And which rdbms? sql just language.. Add sql server to your tag..

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CTE/subquery with conditional aggregation as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProcName
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    WITH CTE AS
    (
       SELECT Type,
              SUM(CASE WHEN Value > 0 THEN Value ELSE 0 END) payroll,
              SUM(CASE WHEN Value < 0 THEN Value ELSE 0 END) refund
       FROM YourTable
       GROUP BY Type
    )
    SELECT CTE.*,
           CTE.payroll + CTE.refund Total
    FROM CTE;
GO;
```

Comment: Thank you. That is what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select type,
       sum(case when part = 'Payroll' then value else 0 end) as payroll,
       sum(case when part = 'Refund' then value else 0 end) as refund
from t
group by type;
```

Why would you want a stored procedure when a simple query does what you want?  I would strongly recommend a view or table-valued function instead.

Comment: I think op want stored procedure.. Not select statement.. But the query already do it.. Just transform it to stored procedure..

Comment: `type` does not have _Payroll_ or _Refund_ values.